# How to have CSS transform:scale act like zoom?

Tags: jquery, css, zooming, transform, scale

I have the following I'd like to replicate cross-browser:

http://jsfiddle.net/AzfGp/19/

It currently works in Chrome. Upon page load or resize, ALL ELEMENTS on the entire page (i.e. all children of my #wrapper) resized proportionately. However, it doesn't work in all browsers. I've read zoom isn't necessarily a good option and that transform:scale(x) is the preferred option. However, I can't get it to work. Here is my attempt:

http://jsfiddle.net/AzfGp/20/

I am using the following jQuery to try and get it to work:

```
 $('*').css({
        'transform', 'scale(' windowH / (540)' )'
        '-webkit-transform', 'scale(' windowH / (540)' )'
        '-moz-transform', 'scale(' windowH / (540)' )'
        '-ms-transform', 'scale(' windowH / (540)' )'
        '-o-transform', 'scale(' windowH / (540)' )'
    });
```

I am using the '*' selector so it targets everything since transform:scale doesn't automatically trickle down to all children like zoom did.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a workable cross-browser solution for this?

Comment: `$('*')..` does a good bit more work than `* { .. }`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... how would the syntax be for that?

Comment: I am not sure if this would solve your problem, but it is always good to keep the standard un-prefixed version (in this case `transform`) at the last.

Comment: That didn't seem to work but good to know to do that. Any reason behind using un-prefixed last?

Comment: `$('*')` first generates the set of *all* current elements and then applies *inline CSS* to each element in turn - all courtesy of jQuery. The `* { .. }` selector *in a stylesheet* doesn't do this as such (it's implemented much more efficiently in the browsers rendering engine, although I leave if/when it will be noticeable or behave differently vaguely specified). It possible to modify *stylesheet rules*, if dynamic values need to be provided. Not sure if/how using a stylesheet rule directly affects the original goal, which is why it is a mere comment.

Comment: @jstacks: It is because browsers that use the prefixes will use them and ignore the properties they don’t understand. Browsers that can support the standards based properties will implement them because they are listed last in your style sheet.

Comment: What is the content of these elements that you want to zoom, is it just an image?

Comment: You were doing a few minor mistakes mate. First the separator between property and value should be ":" and not ",". Second, the `+` operator to append values were missing. It should be like `'-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + windowH / (540) + ' )',`. Check if this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/AzfGp/22/) is what you need.

Comment: Thanks for replies. In regards to using * { .. }. I need dynamic values, so I guess I would need stylesheet rules. However, I'm not sure if CSS stylesheet rules is able to calculate window height / width? Since I need it to be dynamic in relation to that the window size. To Mitchell: it is actually my entire web app that needs to be scaled up (and down) based upon window size. So EVERYTHING must zoom. To Harry: working on those corrections now and crossing fingers!

Comment: @jstacks: I tested on all webkit browsers, firefox and IE10. I can't test in other IE versions :(

Comment: Harry: Well... it's a step closer in that at least it works in Chrome (no FF on this computer) but still not IE. The fiddle itself doesn't work in my IE10. And when applied to my web app, all elements are super oomed and layer on top of one another. Not sure what to make of that.

Comment: @jstacks: that is interesting, because I tested in IE10 and it worked. Any errors in console? Can you try using the latest jQuery version instead of 1.10.1?

Comment: I see the issue in IE10. Not sure why fiddle won't work, but when put into my web app this is what happens (no console error, but transform:scale acts differently in IE10 than Chrome): Every element scales and stays in the same position on screen rather than remaining in the same position relative to respective parent container. So if it scales larger the elements begin to overlap. And if it scales smaller the elements start separating since they shrink and stay in their position. These elements should instead scale as a single unit (as zoom does). If only all browsers did the same thing! :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36899/discussion-between-jstacks-and-harry)